# Laravel : "mcrypt_decrypt(): The IV parameter must be as long as the blocksize"

Tags: laravel, mcrypt

I ran `composer update` on a Laravel application, and now I am getting this error:

> mcrypt_decrypt(): The IV parameter must be as long as the blocksize

What happened?!

Comment: cool
[Ed Rands's comment][1] worked for me 
just to clean up the cookies


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/a/23922994/1539590

Answer (score 26, accepted):

I figured this out. All you have to do is clear your cookies, and everything will be A-okay!

Comment: You only need to clear the cookies, not the history.

Comment: I've got the same problem... It happens when multiple laravel sessions are opened in the same browser (It happened with firefox). I've removed `pma_*` and `laravel_session` cookies and everything went back to normal

Answer (score 4):

You need to change your cipher at app\config\app.php. Having same cipher name was causing that problem for me. I changed the cipher name uniquely & then it worked fine.

Answer (score 2):

This problem can also happen when you run more than one Laravel project/app with same Encryption Key. Just change `key` value in `app/config/app.php` with different value and you ready to go.

Comment: This should really be the accepted answer imo as it tackles the problem from the right angle - eliminating dual Laravel keys - rather than bypassing it.

Answer (score 2):

Just elaborating on the answer from Ifan Iqbal. As he says this happens when running several Laravel installations with the same encryption key. Instead of clearing your cookies, simply create a unique key for each Laravel install you run (good practice by the way).

Go to your terminal and put:

```
php artisan key:generate
```

This will automatically set the encryption key in app/config/app.php and your error will go away.